# Disable ng-model dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I'm replicating the same template multiple times with

```
<div ng-repeat="template in templates track by $index">
 <script type="text/ng-template" id="general">
  <section ui-view="general"></section>
 </script>
</div>
```

So, when i add the next template to my page with the same ng-model bindings on my input, I'm trying to find a way to not let the previous panels from the same template to change their values because of the new values on the latest template. More like disabling the inputs from all the previous panels so that only the latest template is active for the dynamic rendering of values.Whats the best way to achieve this ?

I've tried 
      ng-disabled=field_state

with state toggling between true and false between multiple functions. But this didn't work the way i expected it to work.

Comment: Few questions - is `section` a directive that contains your `input`? When you say "active for dynamic rendering", that means thats the only input bound to the model? And others are just `ng-bind`s? If you are using a directive, the source code of that will help.

Answer (score 2):

You could do two things:

1. bind your `input`s model to the very *index* of your *template*: `<input type="text" id="myInput_{{$index}}" ng-model="repeatedInput.val">` ([Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qa7jojdu/)), or
2. create a *directive* within the `ng-repeat` which wraps your `input` (*directives* create their own *scope*) ([Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vadLjy0g/))

[Learn about `ngRepeat`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat) 
[Learn about *directives*](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive)

Comment: Could you please link an example here. I'm very new to Angular.

Comment: Updated my answer and created two fiddle examples for you.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry if I'm misunderstanding the question. Do you just want to have the last template enabled, and all other disabled? If yes, you could just wrap the script tags with a div.

```
<div ng-repeat="template in templates track by $index">
  <div ng-disabled="$index != templates.length - 1">
    <script type="text/ng-template" id="general">
      <section ui-view="general"></section>
    </script>
  </div>
</div>
```